# Flash Professional HTML5 Canvas : Is it possible to share data between a HTML form and the Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, flash-cc

I have the following use case: There is a given html site with a HTML Form and a Flash Professional HTML5 Canvas. The user has to choose a color in a HTML form. Based on the choice the animation in the HTML5 Canvas shall change. I need to interact between the HTML form and the canvas so that data can be passed from the HTML form to the canvas.

Is there a way to achieve this? With SWF it was possible with ExternalInterface.

Comment: Practically the canvas is just a component in your html page. The javascript which interacts with your canvas is probably declared in your html page. TL;DR You just can call html properties from your javascript. (I think)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything accessible from JavaScript can be used with canvas, more or less.

In this demo the color and text is fetched from HTML input and select elements, and rendered to canvas.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),

    colors = document.getElementById("colors"),  // get colors selector element
    text = document.getElementById("inp"),       // get input text box

    x = 10, y = 10, dx = 4, dy = 5.5;            // just for pin-pong ball

ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";

(function loop() {

  // clear with alpha for trail-effect
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  
  // calc ball speed and direction
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  if (x < 0 || x > c.width) dx = -dx;
  if (y < 0 || y > c.height) dy = -dy;
  
  // reads current value from drop-down (select)
  ctx.fillStyle = colors.value;
  ctx.fillRect(x-5,y-5, 10,10);

  // reads current value from textbox
  ctx.fillText(text.value, x*0.25, 150);

  // loop
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```css
#canvas {border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<!-- These will be available from JavaScript to use with canvas -->
<select id="colors">
  <option value="#d00">Red</option>
  <option value="#090">Green</option>
  <option value="#00d">Blue</option>
  <option value="#fa0">Orange</option>
</select> 
<label for="inp"><b>Type something:</b></label>
<input id="inp" value="Text from HTML input box"><br>
  
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=160></canvas>
```